# How to make script rerun on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, resize, window-resize

I think the question is pretty much self explanatory...

I've got a script that is drawing some graphics across the window. Currently, if I resize the window (like taking it full screen) the script continues to affect only the windows' initial size. It should rerun, responding to the new dimensions.

I've tried adding this to my script.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

});
```

It did run whenever I resized it... but ONLY when I resized it! No more on load... as it also should.

I think I'm on the right path, but what am I missing?

[**Codepen here.**](http://codepen.io/marctannous/pen/RNGjmz)

Comment: can you post your drawling script?

Comment: I could but is it really necessary? Isn't this a "universal" question? The right method should apply to any script, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawStuff() {
   // move here the drawing code ............
};
// call it where the loading process is
drawStuff();

// call it on resize , too
$(window).resize(function() {
   drawStuff();
});
```

To call on loading

If you are using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   drawStuff();
})
```

if not, try this.

```
window.onload = function(){
   drawStuff();
}
```

Comment: didn't change anything. it's only running on load... codepen added to the original post.

Comment: You're mistaking somewhere, post more of your code so that we can examine where you are missing something

Answer (score 1):

```
drawingFunction function(){
 // your drawling code;
}

$(window).resize(function() {
 console.log('window is resized');
 drawingFunction();
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
drawingFunction(); // for onload 
});
```

Comment: This is not run on load, as OP asks. It's only run on resize.

Comment: just use `$( document ).ready(function() {
drawingFunction();
});`

Comment: I change my answer, including onload loading :)

Comment: @Kristiyan It's not working here... what am I missing?

Comment: @JeremyThille You say it looks good, but have you actually tested it? I can't get it working over here... :(

Answer (score 0):

All is ok, but when I maximize or restore window, resize event is fired 2 times. When I press F11 in Firefox to go fullscreen, browser's toolbar is sliding up slowly and resize event is fired up to 40 times. My proposal is to use delay:

```
var timeout;

$(window).resize(function() {
clearTimeout(timeout);
timeout = setTimeout(onResizeOnly, 500);
});

function onResizeOnly()
{
//your code here
}
```

Comment: Just add $( document ).ready(function() {
onResizeOnly(); 
});

Answer (score 0):

In the  tag :

```
<body onresize="drawStuff()">
```

IMHO, it's the easiest way.